# Php curl with digest

Tags: php, linux, curl

```
curl --digest -u username:pass "http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/search" --form image_file=@""
```

when i execute the statement on my terminal with the image_file parameter which is locally             stored it works fine. But how can  i pass remote url in image_file parameter using the   following statement?

Comment: You want the solution in PHP? Look at CURLFile: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: But here how can i send remote image url to this http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/search url so that i get response from that?

Comment: I tried this using my terminal it works fine for my local image but my images are stored on remote server i passed remote image url but not get the response

Comment: I don't think you can pass a url to them. So you have to download the file and then upload it to their server.

Comment: please tell me in php to POST remote image url to api.moodstocks.com/v2/search url and get response from that

Comment: Their API need to support remote image urls which I don't think it does. So you have to download the file first and then upload it to them

Comment: Is there any solution in PHP CURl to get the response of remote image?

Comment: You can use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` to download a file and save it

Comment: No no this is not the right way, Anyway thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Why is that not the right way?

Comment: Because i have multiple images on the server i use this above statement for cron jobs i.e. for multiple images so i think it is foolish to upload image first then hit the statement.

Comment: Then you have to tell moodstocks.com to change their API